# while validating date label and border bottom red color is not showing , yup validation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, material-ui, yup

[color is not showing while validating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k56pz.png)

[label color is not showing while validating for dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kN8P.png)

im expecting that red color should be shown while validating
for datepicker label, border bottom and dropdown label

// DROPDOWN FIELD
this id dropdown field

```
<FormInputDropdown
              name='typeId'
              type='text'
              control={control}
              options={TypeData}
              label='Type'
              helperText={errors?.typeId?.message}
              errors={!!errors.typeId}
              register={register('typeId', {
                onChange: (e) => dispatch(setTypeId(e.target.value)),
              })}
            />
```

// DATE FIELD
this id date field

```
<FormInputDate
              name='acquired'
              control={control}
              label='Date Acquired'
              maxDate={defaultValue.verified}
              helperText={errors?.acquired?.message}
              errors={!!errors.acquired}
              register={register('acquired', {
                onChange: (e) => dispatch(setAcquired(e.target.value)),
              })}
            />
```

// YUP VALIDATION
this is yup validation code

```
const input_schema = yup.object().shape({
  assetTag: yup
    .string()
    .max(128, requiredLimit)
    .required(requiredField)
    .nullable(),
  typeId: yup.string().required(requiredField).nullable(),
  manu: yup.string().max(128, requiredLimit).required(requiredField),
  model: yup.string().max(128, requiredLimit).required(requiredField),
  locationId: yup.string().required(requiredField),
  fundingId: yup.string().required(requiredField),
  buildingId: yup.string().required(requiredField),
  serial: yup.string().max(128, requiredLimit).required(requiredField),
  acquired: yup.date().required().typeError(requiredField),
  verified: yup.date().required().typeError(requiredField),
});
```

```
const useFunction = useForm({
    mode: 'onChange',
    defaultValues: defaultValue,
    resolver: yupResolver(input_schema),
  });
```

Comment: Probably related to this issue: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/29821